# Replace Color With Texture in WebGL

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webgl

In video games only color is applied to help speed up the loading process. After textures are ready, they replace the current colors. Is there a way to do this in `WebGL`? All the tutorials I've seen so far only show how to load in color or texture (not one after the other).

I'd guess that the buffer for each shape needs to be altered after its texture is fully loaded. I would assume this is keyed via an AJAX call that the texture is available, then applied via some kind of JavaScript function. Does `WebGL` have a built in way of doing this without a complicated image loading process?

Comment: Okay, after reading my own question a few months later I understand what I was asking. To fully answer my own question read below. 

To load in textures and color at the same time you need two sets of x-fragment and x-vertex scripts. One for color and another for texture. Since they're pulled in via the DOM you just use the correct shader ID when initializing your objects. Can be color or texture. Hope this helps clueless WebGL soles out there like me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most games that I've seen with the behavior you describe they'll typically start with either per-vertex coloring or a VERY low res texture and "blend up" to the full texture when it becomes available. That sort of smooth transition is tricky, but if all you want is a quick "pop" from one to the other it shouldn't be too much trouble.

The basic route I would take is to create a vertex buffer that has both texture coord and color information, as well as two different shaders. One shader will use the color information, the other will ignore it and use the texture instead. You would signal the mesh to start using the texture-based one as soon as the texture is ready.

As for detecting the image load, that's not hard at all and you don't even need AJAX for it:

```
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Image is done loading, push to texture
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    // Set up any other state needed, such as switching the shader for the mesh
}, true);
image.src = src;
```

I'm not sure how much more help I can give on this subject without posting really large code blocks, but if you're still struggling I can detail some of the other parts.

Comment: Far more simple than I expected. When you say "two different shaders," are you talking about the initial shader that's setup? If so, I would guess that the draw function needs to switch gears and output from the texture at some point.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "initial shader". Are you using a specific tutorial or framework?

Comment: Actually building my own WebGL engine from scratch, follows a lot of ideas and principles from Mozilla's WebGL tutorials. By initial shader I mean the one you use to grab and store shader elements out of the DOM when setting up WebGL (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Okay, so you'd just have a second shader that you define in the DOM. Parsing and compiling it will work the same as the shader that you have now, and you'll just need to make the decision at runtime which one to use when you call `gl.useShader();`

Comment: That makes more sense, gl.useShader() was what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would take is as follows

```
loadTexture(url, initialColor) {

  var tex = gl.createTexture();

  // start with a single color.
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  var pixel = new Uint8Array(initialColor);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, pixel);

  // start loading the image
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {

    // when the image has loaded update the texture.          
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  }
  img.src = url;
  return tex;
}

// Load a tree texture, use brown until the texture loads.
var treeTexture = loadTexture("tree.png", [255, 200, 0, 255]);
// Load a water texture, use blue until it loads.  
var waterTexture = loadTexture("water.jpg", [0, 0, 255, 255]);
```

This is how most of the samples on http://webglsamples.googlecode.com work although they all default to blue textures.

You could easily extend that idea to use a solid color, the load a low-res texture, then when that finishes load a high-res texture.

Note: the code above assumes you are loading power-of-2 textures. If not you'll need to setup your texture parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy, without WebGL having any feature specifically for this, this is something that you get for free just from it being a DOM API. When you load images, anyway you have to implement their 'onload' callback as image loading is asynchronous. So just put in that 'onload' callback whatever code needs to be run to switch from the solid color to the texture.